# How do I create azeotrope mixture?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

I want to decrease the boiling point of a compound. So I need to create an azeotrope mixture from two or three compounds. Where can I find out how make it?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! What is the compound you want to decrease the boiling point of?

Comment: Thank you. I want to decrease the boiling point of methyl jasmonate.

Answer (score 2):

Boiling point can be decrased by lowering pressure over liquide. If you insist on the azeotrop preparation, find azeotrop diagram such as: [image]

or data table such as: [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azeotrope_%28data%29) and determine the composition that must be achieved to obtain the azeotropic mixture. Then mix it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot find a phase diagram like the one above for methyl jasmonate, you can use the principle that a mixture of two dissimilar substances is likely to have a lower boiling point. You might try water plus methyl jasmonate, for example - it should boil slightly below 100C.  Purifying it this way is called steam distillation. Also, another way to lower the boiling point is to lower the ambient pressure - i.e. do a vacuum distillation.